# user email in About service

Tags: google-drive-api

I need to get the user email when I get document permissions. I have seen this problem here

[value attribute for Permissions Resource not populated in responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846293/value-attribute-for-permissions-resource-not-populated-in-responses)

but in about service does not appear my email. I need it because I have a service account and my application need know the user email. I want to avoid call to profile service.
Is this possible? from where I can get the user email?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

As you rightly say, you will have to make a call to the profile service. In some ways it is better like this, because it separates the concerns of the Drive API and the Profile API, and can use specific scoping to let the user know exactly what they are authorizing your app to do.