# User Identification through Google Drive permission list

Tags: google-drive-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [value attribute for Permissions Resource not populated in responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846293/value-attribute-for-permissions-resource-not-populated-in-responses)

I'm experimenting with the Google Drive API and I'm looking at how we might collect data about file permissions for different users on our domain. I'm struggling with the fact that when we try to view the permissions for a particular file id we get a response like the following.

```
  {
   "kind": "drive#permission",
   "etag": "Some valid etag",
   "id": "some id",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/permissions/XXXXXXXXXXX",
   "name": "John Doe",
   "role": "writer",
   "type": "user"
  },
```

The name field references a person by their first and last name rather then their id@domain.com which would be unique. Is there something that exists or could be added that would let us view the permissions with people referenced in this format? We have many people at our institution that have duplicate names. We could have 4 or 5 "John Doe" at the institution and this doesn't help determine which user has access to the file we looked up.

Additional background about my role is that my team is responsible for the domain wide provisioning of accounts and are working on tools that will be used to act on behalf of the institution using service accounts.